# Join in SQL Server with several data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables,

Table 1 is fact_table

```
style   sales
ABC     100
DEF     150
```

and Table 2 is m_product

```
product_code   style   category
ABCS           ABC     Apparel
ABCM           ABC     Apparel
ABCL           ABC     Apparel
DEF38          DEF     Shoes
DEF39          DEF     Shoes
DEF40          DEF     Shoes
```

and I want to join those two tables, I want the result is

```
style   category   sales
ABC     Apparel    100
DEF     Shoes      150
```

I create query like this, but failed

```
Select t1.style, t2.category, t1.sales
From fact_table t1
Inner Join m_product t2
On t1.style = t2.style
```

The result

```
style   category   sales
ABC     Apparel    100
ABC     Apparel    100
ABC     Apparel    100
```

If I am using SUm(sales) and group by, the result will sum all the sales.
Do I have to use average(sales) and then Group By or do you guys have other option ?

I am using SQL Server.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a sub-query:

```
Select t1.style, t2.category, t1.sales
From fact_table t1
Inner Join (SELECT DISTINCT style, category FROM m_product) t2
On t1.style = t2.style
```

BTW, you need to change the DB design to move the category to a separate table

Comment: My vote for saying *move the category to a separate table*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
select p.style, p.category, f.sales
(select distinct style, category
from m_product) p join fact_table f
on p.style = f.style
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Not sure if your table structure is correct. Should you not have product code in the fact table rather than the style. If someone asked you to calculate the sales by product then this strucutre will not be able to answer it.

```
Select t1.style, (select distinct t2.category from
m_product t2
where t1.style = t2.style) as category, t1.sales
From fact_table t1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DISTINCT keyword

```
  Select DISTINCT t1.style, t2.category, t1.sales
    From fact_table t1
    Inner Join m_product t2
    On t1.style = t2.style
```